# Facebooker: Getting it to post to specific pages?

Tags: facebooker

I am trying to post to specific pages and running into an issue. This is what I have where 1234 is a facebook uid

@user = Facebooker::User.new(1234)
@user.session = Facebooker::Session.create(KEY,SECRET)

my_page = Facebooker::Page.new(PAGE_NUMBER)
user.publish_to(@user, :message => @message)

It keeps posting to the user profile and not the page I specify. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try (just a guess)

```
user.publish_to(my_page, :message => @message)
```